# How to gzip decode saved response using fiddler

Tags: gzip, decode, fiddler

I ended up saving a response from fiddler that was not decoded/ungzipped. It seems gzipped but I wasnt able to open it with 7zip. The file is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8518063/ShareX/2016/05/mem

I need to know how to decode the gzip response manually. Is there any option in fiddler to open a previously saved response and decode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some junk in front of and after the gzip stream. If you delete the first six bytes, `20ab\r\n`, and the last seven bytes `\r\n0\r\n\r\n`, then you have a perfectly good gzip stream.

The `20ab` is the length of the gzip stream in bytes, in hexadecimal. So you should be able to decode these inputs in general by reading the length including the new line characters, using that many bytes following, and then throwing out the remainder.